# nginx proxy throws 403 forbidden when query param value has a URL in it

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have an nginx proxy that sits in front of a NodeJS server that is serving up an endpoint that takes a query param like this: `http://mydomain/proxy?url=https://www.google.com`

The endpoint is set up like this:

```js
app.get('/proxy', async (req, res) => {
  const { url } = req.query;
  // do stuff
});
```

And the nginx server config:

```
    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name  mydomain.com;
        #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
   ....
```

I've also tried adding this to the nginx config:

```
    server {
        if ($host = mydomain.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }
```

When I pass anything else into the `url` query param, such as: `http://mydomain/proxy?url=123123`

It works as expected, but the moment I add a fully-qualified URL (which is what I need) which includes `http://` or even the URL encoded version `http%3A%2F%2F`, nginx throws a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: You sure it's not your Express app responding with a 403 (which means _Forbidden_)?

Comment: I'm sure, because even when I don't have my express server running, the 403 forbidden error still shows up from nginx.

Answer (score 1):

*express and nginx as test with* **docker**

express-test/app.js :

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" && !process.env.CI) {
  require("dotenv").config();
}

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.VAR_API_SERVER_PORT;
const host = process.env.VAR_API_SERVER_HOST;
        
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});
    
app.get("/proxy", async (req, res) => {
  const { url } = req.query;
  console.log(url);
  res.send({ url });
});

app.listen(port, host, () =>
  console.log("Listening on: http://" + host + ":" + port)
);
```

express-test/Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
COPY . .

RUN npm install

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV VAR_API_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV VAR_API_SERVER_PORT=4010

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

docker command for run backend test code : (run this codes in backend folder path)

```
1. docker network create my-network || true
2. docker build -t devopsuser1988/backend .
3. docker run -d --network my-network --name backend devopsuser1988/backend
```

nginx-test/app.conf :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://backend:4010/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

nginx-test/Dockerfile :

```
FROM nginx

COPY . /etc/nginx/conf.d

ENV NGINX_ENTRYPOINT_QUIET_LOGS=1

CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

docker commands for run nginx : (please run this codes in nginx-test folder path)

```
1. docker network create my-network || true
2. docker build -t devopsuser1988/nginx-serve-test .
3. docker run -d --network my-network -p 80:80 --name testServe devopsuser1988/nginx-serve-test
```

my test with postman :
[image]